# How to catch a COM error in VBA when there is no return value?

Tags: vba, com

I have a COM method that calls AtlReportError() which returns DISP_E_EXCEPTION

In vba this method is a sub, so there is no result value.
VBA error handling does not catch the expection (as expected)

So, how do I know, in vba, that an exception has been raised in the com method and the returned value is not S_OK?

Comment: What COM application are you talking about? Do you have access to `AtlReportError()` code and the project containing it? How do you declare, `Set` and call the method? The question is too vague to be answered, I think... Theoretically, the sub in discussion itself should send a message (a kind of `MsgBox`, depending on what it means...).

Comment: I think the com side works fine, it returns DISP_E_EXCEPTION as expected. My issue is on the vba side, how to catch this, as for vba, the method is just a sub without a return value (in the .idl file is defined as [id(1),...] HRESULT Copy();

Comment: What does "it returns" mean? Where does it return? Then, you did not answer any of my above clarification questions, so I cannot be of any help. I wish you a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the com method and the HRESULT that was returning. It looks like the hRes parameter when calling AtlReportError() should be negative.

From winnt.h

```
typedef _Return_type_success_(return >= 0) long HRESULT
```